# Facebook Audience Network setAdListner for native ads has been deprecated what is the newer way to do that?

Tags: android, facebook-audience-network

I am trying to implement Facebook native ads in my application. In their documentation, they have mentioned `setAdListner` but in Android Studio I got a warning that `setAddListner` has been deprecated. So I wanna know what is the newer way to do that? Because in their documentation it is not mentioned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAd facebookFullscren
```

set Facebook Ad listner :

```
 facebookFullscren = new com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAd(activity,"YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID");
        InterstitialAdListener adListener = new InterstitialAdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInterstitialDisplayed(Ad ad) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onInterstitialDisplayed: ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onInterstitialDismissed(Ad ad) {
                Log.e(TAG, "facebook Interstitial ad dismissed.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {
                Log.e(TAG, "facebook Interstitial ad failed to load: " + adError.getErrorMessage());

            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onAdLoaded: ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onAdClicked: ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoggingImpression(Ad ad) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onLoggingImpression: ");
            }
        };
```

load Ad:

```
            facebookFullscren.loadAd(facebookFullscren.buildLoadAdConfig()
                .withAdListener(adListener)
                .build());
```

show Ad:

```
if (facebookFullscren != null && facebookFullscren.isAdLoaded()) {
                    facebookFullscren.show();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IntersitialAd ad = new InterstitialAd(Context, String);
ad.loadAd(ad.buildLoadConfig() // LoadConfigBuilder
  .withBid(String)
  .withListener(AdListener)
  .withCacheFlags(CacheFlags)  
  .build()); // builds LoadConfig
```

More details here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/changelog-android#5_6_0